# Connection pool with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why do I have this error?

```
from psycopg2 import pool
from logger_base import log
import sys

class Conexion:
    _DATABASE = 'test_db'
    _USERNAME = 'postgres'
    _PASSWORD = 'Sxmhz97*/'
    _HOST = '127.0.0.1'
    _PORT = 5432
    _MIN_CON = 1
    _MAX_CON = 5
    _pool = None

    @classmethod
    def obtenerPool(cls):
        if cls._pool is None:
            try:
                cls._pool = pool.SimpleConnectionPool(cls._MIN_CON, cls._MAX_CON,
                                                      host=cls._HOST,
                                                      user=cls._USERNAME,
                                                      password=cls._PASSWORD,
                                                      database=cls._DATABASE,
                                                      port=cls._PORT)
                return cls._pool
            except Exception as e:
                log.error(f'Ocurrio un error al obterner el pool: {e}')
                sys.exit()

    @classmethod
    def obtenerConexion(cls):
        conexion = cls.obtenerPool().getconn()
        log.debug(f'Conexion obtenida del pool: {conexion}')
        return conexion

    @classmethod
    def liberarConexion(cls, conexion):
        cls.obtenerPool().putconn(conexion)
        log.debug(f'Regresamos la conexion al pool: {conexion}')

    @classmethod
    def cerrarConexiones(cls):
        cls.obtenerPool().closeall()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    conexion1 = Conexion.obtenerConexion()
    conexion2 = Conexion.obtenerConexion()

    print(conexion1)
    print(conexion2)
```

```
03:01:55 PM: DEBUG [Conexion.py:33] Conexion obtenida del pool: <connection object at 0x0000022F9BED29B0; dsn: 'user=postgres password=xxx dbname=test_db host=127.0.0.1 port=5432', closed: 0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\DATOS\Python\capa_datos\Conexion.py", line 49, in <module>
    conexion2 = Conexion.obtenerConexion()
  File "f:\DATOS\Python\capa_datos\Conexion.py", line 32, in obtenerConexion
    conexion = cls.obtenerPool().getconn()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getconn'
```

Comment: Does it work once? A new pool is returned in `if cls._pool is None:` , but the existing pool is not returned when not None.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `cls._pool` was not `None` in `obtenerPool(cls)`.

So the body of the statement `if cls._pool is None:` was not executed, and since the only `return` statement of `obtenerPool` is inside this `if` statement, it returned `None`.